# Why Does Vue 3 Only Render First SVG in Sprite?

Tags: vue.js, svg, sprite

I have a `Vue 3.1.1` project and I'm seeing a bizarre issue. If I put an SVG file in my template that references a sprite, only the first instance of it appears.

Here's my template code:

```
<template>
<div>
  <svg>
    <use href="@/assets/images/icons-master.svg#project"></use>
  </svg>
  <svg>
    <use href="@/assets/images/icons-master.svg#project"></use>
  </svg>
</div>
</template>
```

Here's how it renders in the DOM (tested in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari):

[image]

See how it removes the `#project` from the file path on the second SVG?

If I try a different filename, I can see the first instance of where the file is used, and subsequent SVGs have the `#id` removed and don't show up.

My SVG file is structured as follows.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="display: none;">
  <symbol id="project" viewbox="0 0 16 17">
    <g ...>
      <path ...>
      </path>
    </g>
  </symbol>
</svg>
```

This used to work fine in `Vue 2.x`. Is this incorrect SVG syntax or a bug in Vue?

Answer (score 0):

This might be [a bug with Vite](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/3822), but it looks like a workaround is to not use the `@` path component from `vite.config.js`:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import path from 'path'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, '/src'),
    },
  }
})
```

So the workaround is to change the SVG path to this:

```
src/assets/images/icons-master.svg#project
```

Where `src` replaces `@`.